# Pass mock objects as JUnit parameter to test methods with parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am using junit parameterized approach to do unit testing.

Initially I used to follow the normal parameterized approach to test my workflow[1](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests). 
But later I found this document [2](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/Full-Guide.md) which provides a better and concise approach to test using parameters.
However, I cannot figure out a way to pass mock objects to the test method.

```
@TestWith({
        "null, mock(B.class),mock(C.class)",
        "mock(A.class), null, mock(C.class)",
        "mock(A.class), mock(B.class), null"
})
public void test_workflow(final A Aclass,final B Bclass,final C Cclass)
{
    assertThat....
}
```

I am getting illegal argument exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot interpret string "mock(B.class)" as a class B.class
    at com.googlecode.zohhak.internal.coercing.CoercingService.coerceParameter(CoercingService.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.zohhak.internal.coercing.CoercingService.coerceParameters(CoercingService.java:33)
    at com.googlecode.zohhak.internal.Executor.calculateParameters(Executor.java:28)
    at com.googlecode.zohhak.internal.junit.ParametrizedFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(ParametrizedFrameworkMethod.java:22)

Does anyone know how can I pass mock objects as parameters to the test method? It will be a great help, I will keep trying to figure it out on my end.

Comment: Maybe add the class the static `mock()` method comes from, such as `"Mockito.mock(B.class)"`?

Comment: I have added static import, but even after adding Mockito.mock I am getting the same error. The issue here is, it is interpreting it as a string, probably there should be some internal converter I can override to convert the string appropriately (not sure, just a guess).

Comment: I guess I found the answer, not sure though, it uses default coecer to convert the string. I guess I need to make some changes or build my custom coecer to convert the mock objects. https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/zohhak/api/DefaultCoercer.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/Full-Guide.md#basic-usage

> Zohhak by default supports:
>
> ```
> primitives and their wrappers
> nulls
> enums
> String
> BigInteger, BigDecimal (since 1.1.0)
> ```
>
> and types assignable from them (eg. Number, CharSequence, Object).
>   Parameters are separated with comma, edge white characters are trimmed
>   (unless apostrophes are used).

So you need to write a coersion method.
Which will read class name and create the mock object.
https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/Full-Guide.md#registering-coercions

Comment: yes. That worked. I added my custom coercions. Thanks.